# How to access the SharePoint 2007 and 2013 portal with specified credential

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, 2007

How to access the SharePoint 2007 and 2013 portal with specified credential

- Specify the credential via code (username, password)
- Then open the site collection with that account

Currently we use below code; with assumption that the user will be the logged in user. 
SPSite.Open("URL") ; this should be changed to run the code in behave of different user domain.

Scenario:
I am in Server A and want to access the farm in Server B with different domains.

Answer (score 0):

To access SharePoint 2013 Portal you can use the below code.

```
//Get Request Digest
HttpWebRequestendpointRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("<<site
url>>/_api/contextinfo");
endpointRequest.Method = "POST";
endpointRequest.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
endpointRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
endpointRequest.ContentLength = 0;
NetworkCredential cred = newSystem.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
endpointRequest.Credentials = cred;
HttpWebResponseendpointResponse = (HttpWebResponse)endpointRequest.GetResponse();
//Sample Post Command
HttpWebRequestendpointRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("<<REST URL>>");
endpointRequest.Method = "POST";
endpointRequest.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
endpointRequest.ContentType = "application/json;odata=verbose";
NetworkCredential cred = newSystem.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
endpointRequest.Credentials = cred;
String username = "username";
String password = "password";
StringuserPassword = username + ":" + password;
byte[] byteArrayUP = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(userPassword);
endpointRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer" + byteArrayUP);
stringpostData = "{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.<<ListTitle>>ListItem' }, 'Column1':
'Text1','Column2':'Text2'}";
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
// endpointRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
endpointRequest.Headers.Add("X-RequestDigest", digest);
// Get the request stream.
StreamdataStream = endpointRequest.GetRequestStream();
// Write the data to the request stream.
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
// Close the Stream object.
dataStream.Close();
HttpWebResponseendpointResponse = (HttpWebResponse)endpointRequest.GetResponse();
```

https://www.dsouzajoel.com/2015/12/09/connect-to-sharepoint-on-premise-using-external-applications/